# Unity - possible to have bending grass? Mesh?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, terrain, game-development

Ok here is what Im trying to achieve - when user's feet collide with grass mesh, the mesh is secured to the ground at the base but the tops move away, then bounce back when foot is no longer there:

[image]

This example, and everything I've found however, are using billboarding/2d as grass. I want 3d, like these:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/vegetation/plants/grass-toon-76674

Where some sort of collision is occurring, or Ive tried experimenting with unity's trees. Trying to find the most CPU/GPU effective (for Oculus app or mobile) way to do this.

Is this possible - to have interactive, 3d not 2d grass?

Comment: Having colliders in each grass would kill performance.. just use shader that bends (offsets) vertices based on player location. Asset store has many 3d bending grass plugins toon.

Comment: Could only find one toon (the one I listed) for toon grass, and need to be interactive.. would you suggest any?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to model each blade of grass as several bars connected by universal joints (I'm not sure what kind they would be in unity, but that is the mechanisms term).

Each joint could have a torque proportional to its angle, so the more you bend it, the harder it tries to flick back. Then its just a matter of adding forces to the blade structures as you bump into them.

This is more of a engineering solution than a programming one, and would require a little bit of math, so its probably not ideal. but it should work.